# I want to create a fill pattern for a slice for 3D printing in JavaFX/Java

Tags: java, svg, javafx, overlay, stl-format

I create SVG slices from STL files.  The SVG files consist of many many lines.  The short version is I can't use the built in functionality of JavaFX to create a fill pattern of the SVG.  The reason was something to do with the SVG not being created correctly, because the code does a move and then line and then move and then line.  To use the fill feature I think you need to have a single move and then many lines.  Too long ago to remember the exact issue.

So this is what I am doing now to solve the issue
I store the fill pattern, honeycomb fill pattern, in a file.  This can ofcourse be stored in memory, but it is for testing.  I then store a the hollow slice in a second file.  I need to combine the two so that only the parts of the honeycomb that are inside the layer/slice display and the rest is removed.  The honeycomb should be white and the slice should also be white.  The plan was to make the honeycomb white when I copy it over to the slice.

I tried two methods.

The first method I tried was to copy pixels from the fill pattern to the layer/slice.  I tried to find where the lines are of the layer and then try to figure out where the inside and the outside is.  I failed.  Code will be attached to the bottom of this question.

The second way I tried was to use the blendMode, but none of the modes seem to do what I need it to do.

**First method code**
I tried saving the honeycomb and layer in different colours, I tried saving them on top of each other and then remove honeycomb.  Here you can see I am trying to figure out what is inside and what is outside, but I couldn't make it work

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Mandibular\\MandibularsolidNOreferencepoints.gizmofill0.gizmoslice.png");
            BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(file);

            WritableImage writableImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImage, null);

            PixelReader pixelReader = writableImage.getPixelReader();
            int width = (int) writableImage.getWidth();
            int height = (int) writableImage.getHeight();

            WritableImage dest = new WritableImage(width, height);
            PixelWriter writer = dest.getPixelWriter();
            boolean isOnLine = false;
            boolean previousIsOnLine = false;
            boolean isInside = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 00; y < height; y++) {
                    // reading a pixel from src image,
                    // then writing a pixel to dest image
                    Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
                    double red = color.getRed();
                    double green = color.getGreen();
                    double blue = color.getBlue();

                    if (red == 0 && green == 1 && blue == 0) {
                        //isInside = !isInside;
                        isOnLine = true;
                    } else {
                        previousIsOnLine = isOnLine;
                        isOnLine = false;
                    }

                    if (previousIsOnLine) {
                        isInside = !isInside;
                    }

                    /*if (isOnLine && red == 1 && green == 0 && blue == 0) {
                        isInside = true;
                        isOnLine = false;
                    }*/

                    if (isOnLine || isInside) {
                        writer.setColor(x, y, color);
                    }
                    /*if (isOnLine || isInside && (red > 0 && green == 0 && blue == 0)) {
                        writer.setColor(x, y, Color.WHITE);
                    }*/

                }
            }


            File outputFile = new File("C:\\Temp\\Mandibular\\test.png");
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(dest, null), "png", outputFile);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**Second method using blend**
I tried the different blendModes and ended with the last one layerView.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_ATOP); that clearly doesn't do what I need.  I just tested each one to see what might work

```
package javafxapplication15;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JavaFXApplication15 extends Application {
    private void doWork() {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Mandibular\\MandibularsolidNOreferencepoints.gizmofill0.gizmoslice.png");
            BufferedImage layerImage = ImageIO.read(file);

            file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Mandibular\\MandibularsolidNOreferencepoints.gizmofill-1.gizmoslice.png");
            BufferedImage fillImage = ImageIO.read(file);

            WritableImage layerWritableImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(layerImage, null);
            WritableImage fillWritableImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(fillImage, null);

            WritableImage temp = copyImageOntoFillPattern(fillWritableImage, layerWritableImage);


            File outputFile = new File("C:\\Temp\\Mandibular\\test.png");
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(temp, null), "png", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication15.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    private WritableImage copyImageOntoFillPattern(final WritableImage fillPatternImage, final WritableImage sourceImage) {

        ImageView fillPatternView = new ImageView(fillPatternImage);
        ImageView layerView = new ImageView(sourceImage);
        layerView.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_ATOP);

        Group blend = new Group(fillPatternView, layerView);

        blend.snapshot(null, sourceImage);
        SnapshotParameters param = new SnapshotParameters();
        final WritableImage snapshotCombined = blend.snapshot(param, null);
        return snapshotCombined;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
                doWork();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image: Layer]

[image: Honeycomb fill pattern and layer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked around for maybe an hour changing a .fxml file

Here is the contents of the file, I need to convert it to code that I can run, but shouldn't be too hard now.

The layer needed to be filled, the fill colour doesn't seem to matter.  I made it green so that it is visible on the website here, but I will probably create it as white when I create it in my slicer.  I also made the honeycomb red so that it is easier to see.  I am showing an image of SceneBuilder where it worked

I will now just create the honeycomb as white and the layer as solid white and things will be great

[image: Slice or Layer]

[image: Honeycomb]

[image: Combination in Scene Builder]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Group blendMode="HARD_LIGHT">
         <children>
            <ImageView blendMode="DIFFERENCE" cache="true" fitHeight="418.0" fitWidth="591.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@outline.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView blendMode="SRC_ATOP" fitHeight="451.0" fitWidth="688.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@honeycomb.png" />
               </image>
               <effect>
                  <Blend mode="ADD" />
               </effect>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </Group>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```